# Why are my tailwind css classes not working?

Tags: tailwind-css

Hi i am new to tailwind css, i am trying to do a portfolio website with next js tailwind css but my classes are not working and i do not know why.

tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This are my globals.css:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "burtons";
  src: url("../public/Burtons.otf");
}
```

And this is my index.tsx:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import { BsFillMoonStarsFill } from 'react-icons/bs';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Mateo Ghidini Dev</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main className='bg-white px-10'>
        <section className='min-h-screen'>
          <nav className='py-10 mb-12 flex justify-between'>
            <h1 className='text-xl'>Developed by Mateo Ghidini</h1>
            <ul className='flex items-center'>
              <li>
                <BsFillMoonStarsFill/>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </section>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Only my html tags are working. Any reason why?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes are working in your HTML tags then the problem must be the content array in your tailwind.config.js. You are adding tailwind classes in a file whose path is not included in the content array so Tailwind is likely purging those classes and not applying them.
Modify it like this and try:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Also make sure that your index file or any other file where you are applying the classes are inside src folder and if you want to target other folders like `pages` in case of next.js then mention their paths too in the content array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your tailwind classes don't get shipped. Please have a look at the Tailwind docs for that, you can either use the tailwind CLI in a manual approach or use PostCSS if you're not using a framework like next.js:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation